# How to include data with mongo image in kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to get my app running on minikube, reachable at the minikube ip address. Below are the commands I am using to get it running. It all works as I want it to (if I try to log in, it returns the expected 401 since the mongo DB is empty).

I would like to actually include a database in my app with, say, an existing user. I cannot find a clear way with how to include data (say in a  tar file that works with mongo) with what I am doing. How can I accomplish this?

```
### Get mongo up
docker pull mongo:3.2
kubectl run mongo --image=mongo:3.2 --port=27017
kubectl expose deployment mongo

### Get API up
cd /api
docker build -t api:v1 .
kubectl run api --image=api:v1 --port=3000 --env="MONGODB_URI=mongodb://mongo:27017/myapp-dev"
kubectl apply -f api-deployment.yml
kubectl expose deployment api --type=LoadBalancer

### Get dashboard up
docker build -t myapp-dashboard:v1 .
kubectl apply -f ./tooling/minikube/myapp-dashboard-qa-config-map.yml
kubectl apply -f ./tooling/minikube/myapp-dashboard-deployment.yml
kubectl expose deployment myapp-dashboard --type=LoadBalancer

### Ingress setup
minikube addons enable ingress
kubectl create -f ingress.yml
kubectl apply -f ./tooling/minikube/ingress.yml
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The nice way of doing it making use of the `initdb` infrastructure in the `mongo` image. The `mongo:3.2` includes an [`entrypoint` shell script](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/3.2/docker-entrypoint.sh) that iterates trough `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*.{sh,js}` (in the container).

Depending on the type of data you need to insert into the newly made database using a [`ConfigMap`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) or a [`Secret`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) as a volume is the way to go. But you can't do that with `kubectl run`.

**1.** Create a `mongo.yaml` like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mongo:3.2
        name: mongo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mongo-initdb
          mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      volumes:
      - name: mongo-initdb
        configMap:
          name: mongo-initdb
```

**2.** Create `createuser.sh` like this (just an [example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-users/)):

```
mongo <<EOF
use reporting
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "reportsUser",
    pwd: "12345678",
    roles: [
       { role: "read", db: "reporting" },
       { role: "read", db: "products" },
       { role: "read", db: "sales" },
       { role: "readWrite", db: "accounts" }
    ]
  }
)
EOF
```

**3.** Create the [`ConfigMap`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-users/):

```
$ kubectl create configmap mongo-initdb --from-file=createuser.sh
configmap "mongo-initdb" created
```

**4.** Create the mongo deployment (instead of `kubectl run mongo --image=mongo:3.2 --port=27017`):

```
$ kubectl apply -f mongo.yaml
deployment "mongo" created
```

**5.** Check the logs:

```
$ kubectl logs -f deploy/mongo
[...]
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/createuser.sh
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.17
[...]
Successfully added user: {
[...]
```

As I mentioned a very similar solution can be done using [`Secrets`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) for sensitive data. The `kubectl create configmap --from-file=...` command also accepts a name of a directory instead of a file and will work as expected.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer! I got it working with your example, but I am now trying to import a database, and facing some problems. Inside the `createuser.sh` script I am trying to curl `myapp-db.tar.bz2` so I can `mongorestore` it, but I the pod breaks and the logs say `curl: command not found`. I tried adding in `apt-get` scripts but the logs say `Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)`. How can I properly run scripts here? I'll post my full shell file below:

Comment: `mongo myapp-dev --eval "db.dropDatabase()"

apt-get update && apt-get install curl && apt-get install bzip2

curl https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/xxxxxxxx -o myapp-db.tar.bz2

bzip2 -dc mapp-db.tar.bz2 | tar xvf -

mongorestore --db myapp-dev myapp-dev

mongo myapp-dev --eval 'db.users.update({}, {$set: {hashedPassword: "fwaPwkoIpS4y4aWA+uljXWIlyjTxUzkU+IgK4+B8m+ZhyBrWwM/N/oGfUj0ERAcwnXCOImkOvbvDMH/BAmN8FA==", salt: "YfnL4jUxfbYY6Y3/w8P8KA=="}}, {multi: true})'

mongo myapp-dev --eval 'db.getCollection("users").dropIndex("referral_1")'`

Comment: The initdb scripts are not running as root that's why you can't do `apt-get update/install` from there. In the `containers:` section under `name` etc just add `command: ["sh","-c","apt-get update && apt-get install ... && exec docker-entrypoint.sh"]`. That should do the trick as quick fix. Better yet, build your own mongo image that has curl :-)

Comment: It looks like it works up until the `exec docker-entrypont.sh`. I get the following error `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 4: 1: unbound variable`

Comment: I have `command: ["sh","-c","apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y curl && apt-get install -y bzip2 && exec docker-entrypoint.sh"]` under `containers` as the last item

Comment: My mistake. Add `mongod` too. This is WAI: `command: ["sh","-c","apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl bzip2 && exec docker-entrypoint.sh mongod"]` . But again, building your own image is a much nicer solution than this.

Comment: Can I achieve the same when I am trying to use the replicaset? I am using stateful set but not sure how to invoke these shell scripts